# Why Ubuntu 11.04 under 64b is not able to identify sunspots on serial port?

Tags: 11.04, serial-port

I am running SunSpot sdk under ubuntu 11.04,64bit.I have connected my sunspot basestation and after running ant info for my spot it is not possible to be identified. I am getting the following:

```
ant info
Buildfile: /home/home/SunSPOT/sdk/build.xml

-pre-init:

-do-init:

-post-init:

-warn-jar-file:

init:

-override-warning-find-spots:

-prepare-conditions-for-find-spots:

-find-shared-basestation:

-run-spotfinder:
     [exec] Using Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) to probe Sun SPOTS...

-check-spotfinder-result:

-decide-whether-to-run-spotselector:

-run-spotselector:
     [java] Please wait while connected Sun SPOTs are examined...
     [java] No serial port available
     [java] Java Result: 255

-collect-spotselector-result:

-clean-up-spotselector-output-file:

-spotselector-fail:

BUILD FAILED
/home/home/SunSPOT/sdk/ant/find-spots.xml:367: Spotselector failed or was cancelled

Total time: 11 seconds
```

I have also installed rxtx from here http://www.cloudhopper.com/opensource/rxtx/ for linux-64b and i am able to see the following after running cat dev/ttyACM0 and rebooting my spot:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0 


** VM stopped: exit code = 0 ** 

*EL*:S Sun SPOT bootloader (red-090706) 
*EL*:S Sun SPOT bootloader (red-090706) 
*EL*:S Sun SPOT bootloader (red-090706) 
*EL*:S Sun SPOT bootloader (red-090706) 
*EL*:S Sun SPOT bootloader (red-090706) 
*EL*:S Sun SPOT bootloader (red-090706) 
*EL*:S Sun SPOT bootloader (red-090706) 
*EL*:S Sun SPOT bootloader (red-090706) 

Squawk VM Starting (red-090706)...
base station ready ...
```

and to check my usb:

```
dmesg | grep usb
[    0.729536] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.729553] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.729595] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.390046] usb 2-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
[   18.176287] input: CNF9011 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/input/input5
[   18.178362] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  150.120103] usb 4-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
[  150.394719] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
```

Any idea?It seems that serial is not found.

Comment: Are you still looking foe help with this, or did you find an answer? If you did find an answer please consider adding it here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found, was to install the 32 bit java, and use that instead. In that way could I communicate with the sun spot using the ant scripts, and deploy.

I still got problems when communicating from netbeans, but netbeans could compile the projects.